# mailkit Add imap folder not visible

Tags: c#, .net, mailkit, create-directory

I'm trying to add folder to inbox as follows:

```
var _client = new ImapClient();
_client.Connect(hostName, portNumber, useSsl);
_client.Authenticate(username, password);
_client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
_client.Inbox.Create("Name", true);
```

Everything goes fine, the Create function returns created folder, the _client.Inbox.GetSubfolders() returns list that contains new created folder as well, however I can't see this folder in e-mail client application (such as Thunderbird).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thunderbird may only be showing you subscribed folders. If that is the case, then you will also want to do `newFolder.Subscribe ();`

I should also point out that there's no reason to `Open()` the inbox before creating a child folder.

You only need to `Open()` a folder in order to read messages from it.